# De-identified longitudinal K-12 student letter grade data

Tags: data-request, education

Does anyone know of any de-identified longitudinal student-level letter grade data for a K-12 school system?

I'm aware that this data would be sensitive--I'm not interested in demographics or anything like that, just trying to model individual teacher effects on student performance.  As such, an ideal dataset would include students graded over multiple years with anonymized IDs, where each student letter grade is associated with an (anonymized) teacher ID.

Answer (score 3):

the two longitudinal federal surveys that might have this information in some sort of useful clustering pattern are

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20study%20of%20adolescent%20to%20adult%20health%20%28addhealth%29

and

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20surveys%20%28nls%29

there's a lot of assessment data in pisa, but it's cross-sectional

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/program%20for%20international%20student%20assessment%20%28pisa%29